# Store attribute as binary or String (JSON)

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I have to store some attributes in DynamoDB and confused if some of JSON attributes should be stored as String/Binary. I understand that storing it as binary will reduce the size of attribute.

I considered DDB limits as 1 Read/Write IOPS consumes 4KB.

My total data in item is less than 4KB even if I store it as String.

What things should I consider to choose binary vs String ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your item sizes are less than 4KB uncompressed, whether to encode attributes in `byte` or `string` depends on whether the attribute will be a partition / range key of the table and your typical read patterns.

A partition key has a max sz of 2048 bytes, or ~2Kb. 
A sort key (if you specify one on the table) has a max sz of 1024 bytes, or ~1Kb.

If you foresee your `string` attribute exceeding the above maximums on any items, it would make sense to compress to binary first to keep your attribute sizes in congruence with DynamoDB requirements.

Depending on how many items are in your typical query and your tolerance for throttled queries, your RCU's may not satisfy a Query / Scan where you perform the read in a single request.

For instance, 
If you have 1KB items and want to query 100 items in a single request, your RCU req will be as follows:
`(100 * 1024 bytes = 100 KB) / 4 KB = 25 read capacity units`
Converting some attributes to binary could reduce your RCU requirement in this case. Again it largely depends on your typical usage pattern.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html#HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.Reads